# How to set up proxy for Java Application running as windows service

Tags: java, windows, proxy, java-service-wrapper

I am facing a weird issue. I have a java application which runs perfectly under proxy, but when the application is setup to run as a windows service  it doesn't work. I have tried setting jvm with these parameter -Dhttp.proxyHost=10.0.0.100 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8800 but still it is not working. The issue seems to coming when running the Application as a windows service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `_JAVA_OPTIONS` system environment variable then restart the service.

[image: _JAVA_OPTIONS]

**NOTE: This will affect all the java application running in the machine**